# Wordpress - jQuery - easeOutBounce not working

Tags: jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.learningjquery.com/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js">    
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.homeslider, #left, #right').hover(function(){
    $('.slidercaptions').animate({"height": "47px", "padding-top": "25px"}, {duration: 10, easing: 'easeOutBounce'});
            }, function(){
            $('.slidercaptions').animate({"height": "0", "padding-top": "0"},     10);
        })
    })
</script>
```

Once hover in .homeslider element .slidercaptions should gain height and bounce. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any clue would be appreciated. Thanks

P.S. 
I also included Easing plugin.

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script( 'easing' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', false);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [jquery-effects-core](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)

```
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery-effects-core");
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```

It'll load the `WP`'s standard script and it contains the `easing` functionality. Use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to load scripts, this is the proper way to add scripts in `WP`, also you have multiple versions of `jQuery` linked.

Answer (score 0):

@Sheikh Heera - Thanks, I found my mistake, i was looking in the wrong file. I forgot to remove my first style set for .slidercaptions in css file. Transitions should be removed.

```
.slidercaptions{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s easen-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
```

}